# Как убрать выделение строки с курсором в vs code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, настройка

Как изменить настройки в VSCode, чтобы убрать выделение строки, в которой находится курсор.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: картинка не загружается....

Comment: проблема в том, что место пробела выделяется фоном

Comment: вот на хостинг картинку залил, раз сюда не грузится: https://ibb.co/TtCt2zX

Answer (score 1):

Первоначально

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все достаточно просто делается через настройки

1. Нажмите <kbd>F1</kbd>
2. В появившейся строке наберите `settings` и выберите `Preferences: Open User Settings`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. В строке поиска настроек введите `lineHighlight` и в самой настройке выберите `none`
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
4. Все, выделение строки пропало
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]