# Как убрать выделение строки с курсором в PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains, settings, настройки

Скажите пожалуйста, как убрать выделение строки с курсором в PyCharm?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) Зачем? Разве из-за этого код хуже становиться? :P 2) Так легче определить на какой вы сейчас линии кода.

Comment: ΝNL993, я с вами согласен. Но эта полоса очень и очень раздражает глаз.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Страница настроек **Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Editor | Caret row**

Нужно убрать галочку с **Background**. Или поменять цвет на приемлимый.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Используйте комбинацию клавиш alt + shift + insert. Или используйте правую кнопку мыши, снимите галочку с Column selection mode.

Comment: Smart Legion Lab, не сработало. Это что-то другое.

Comment: Нужно такое решение как здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1397223/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2-vs-code

только для JetBrains.